# Datatype declaration significance in pointer to pointer (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory

Is there a difference between **pointer to integer-pointer** (`int**`) and **pointer to character-pointer** (`char**`), and any other case of pointer to pointer?

Isn't the memory block size for any pointer is the same, so the sub-datatype doesn't play a role in here?

Is it just a semantic distinction with no other significance?

Why not to use just `void**`?

Comment: Yes it's all semantics, but semantics is very important when you use these constructs.

Comment: Why not just use `void**`? Why not just write machine code?

Comment: "Is it just a semantic distinction with no other significance?" - the whole "types" thing is just semantics. Are you saying types are not significant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why *should* we use `void**` when you want a pointer to a `char *`? Why should we *not* use `char **`?

With `char **`, you have type safety. If the pointer is correctly initialized and not null, you know that by dereferencing it once you get a valid `char *` - and by dereferencing that pointer, in turn, you get a `char`.

Why should you ignore this advantage in **type safety**, and instead play pointer Russian roulette with `void**`?

Answer (score 5):

The difference is in type-safety. `T**` implicitly interprets the data as T. `void**`, however, needs to be manually casted first. And no, pointers are not all 4 / 8 bytes on 32 / 64bit architectures respectively. Member function pointers, for instance, contain offset information too, which needs to be stored in the pointer itself (in the most common implementation).

Answer (score 5):

Most C implementations use the same size and format for all pointers, but this is not required by the C standard.

Some machines do not have byte addressing, so the C implementation implements it by using shifts and other operations. In these implementations, pointers to larger types, such as `int`, may be normal addresses, but pointers to `char` would have to have both a machine address and a byte-within-word offset.

Additionally, C makes use of the type information for a variety of purposes, including reducing mistakes made by programmers (possibly giving warnings or errors when you attempt to use a pointer to `int` where a pointer to `float` is needed) and optimization. Regarding optimization, consider this example:

```
void foo(float *array, int *limit)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < *limit; ++i)
         array[i] = <some calculation>;
}
```

The C standard says a compiler may use the fact that `array` and `limit` are pointers to different types to conclude that they do not overlap. Given this rule, the C implementation may evaluate `*limit` once when the loop starts, because it knows it will not change during the loop. Without this rule, the compiler would have to assume that one of the assignments to `array[i]` might change `*limit`, and it would have to load `*limit` from memory in each iteration.

Comment: That's new for me, can you give an example?

Comment: @Stefan as strange as it may seem, some architectures can't address bytes - that is, the smallest atom you can take the address of is for instance a 2 byte unit.